# Implementing self-made attribute mask doubles combo boxes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qt-designer

I'm working on a QGIS-Project and I tried to design my own formmask/attributemask with QT Designer. I use QGIS 3.28.12

Most of the Mask works perfectly fine, except for two things.

One of which I'm asking here.

I've noticed, that when I implement my mask, it has an issue when I use "Relations References" - it doubles the comboboxes.

I used a QComboBox.

If I use "Value Relation" it works perfectly fine but I'd like to use the first one, since I can then input a display expression, which I can't if I use the second option.

Is it even possible to use Relation Reference with an own Attributemask?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After all this time and with help from a QGIS Developer we found out, that there's actually nothing wrong with the funktion and ui-form...
it seems the problem is a bug in newer QGIS-Versions, so not much I can do about it.

If a solution is found to fix the bug or some workaround, I'll post here as an answer.